# Trouble fetching data from service in Angular 14

Tags: html, angular, service

I have problems fetching data from the service.
This is my component code:

```js
import { Component, OnInit,Injectable, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { DashboardService } from '../dashboard.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  bigchart !: any[];
  cards !: any[];
  
  constructor(private dashboardService: DashboardService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.bigchart = this.dashboardService.bigchart();
    this.cards = this.dashboardService.cards();
  }

}
```

This is the service code:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DashboardService {

  constructor() { }
  bigchart() {
    return [{ 
      name: 'Current',
      data: [0.54, 0.53, 0.57, 0.64, 0.57, 0.48]
    }, {
      name: 'Voltage',
      data: [133.36, 134.15, 132.43, 131.15, 135.17, 133.21]
    }, {
      name: 'Motor Speed',
      data: [15, 16, 17, 12, 15, 19]
    }];
  }
  cards() {
    return [15, 16, 17, 12];
  }
}
```

This is the HTML code:

```html
<div>
   <app-widget-area  [name]="bigchart" [data]="bigchart"></app-widget-area>
</div>
<br>
<mat-divider></mat-divider>
<br>
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAllign="space-between center" fxLayoutGap="20px" class="stats-cards">
    <mat-card fxFlex="25">
        <app-widget-card label="Current Num"  total="16k" percentage="75" [data]="cards"></app-widget-card>
    </mat-card>
    <mat-card fxFlex="25">
        <app-widget-card label="Current Num"  total="16k" percentage="75" [data]="cards"></app-widget-card>
    </mat-card>
    <mat-card fxFlex="25">
        <app-widget-card label="Current Num"  total="16k" percentage="75" [data]="cards"></app-widget-card>
    </mat-card>
    <mat-card fxFlex="25">
        <app-widget-card label="Current Num"  total="16k" percentage="75" [data]="cards"></app-widget-card>
    </mat-card>
</div>
<br>
```

The card works fine but the with the big card, the chart are not showing any data. I think its probably because I declare the type of the data received in the mat-widget-area to be `any[]`

```js
@Input() data!: any[];
```

and the data from the service appears to have 2 inputs (name and data). I dont know how to fix this

Comment: did you log this.bigchart?

Comment: Of course, using `any` for all variables is completely wrong! But this doesn't impact result because type definitions are stripped at compile time. Why you think that problem is with service? Have you inspected `this.bigchart` after OnInit? Is your component `app-widget-area` properly tested?

Comment: Could you provide code for `app-widget-area`? It looks like it is same input for object and for primitive value, so maybe case with object is not handled properly?

Comment: In app-widget-area I defined input like this:  '@Input() name !: string; @Input() data !: number[];'